# Window.Toolkit.Uwp.A ContentBuilder generated from the Notifications class only works in win 10?

Tags: c#, windows, notifications, toast

I am developing a automation project. I have to send notifications to user. I am using Windows.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications ToastContenBuilder. What I was wondering Window.Toolkit.Uwp.A ContentBuilder generated from the Notifications class only works in win 10 ?

I tried to run this app on Win 8.1 and i got 'failed to initialize notification' error. Why am I getting such an error ?

Comment: for windows 8 you need to use something else. the UWP way requires specific TFs.
have a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh969156(v=win.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN